# How to trim a log file using grep command

Tags: shell, grep, winscp

For example: If below is the content of my log file, I want to keep only the contents between the first occurrence of value '2018' and last occurrence of '2018'

```
sssssssssssssssssssss
ddddddddddddddddddddd
2018fffffffffffffffff
dddddd2018ddddddddddd
wwww2018wwwwwwwwwwwww
aaaaaaaaaaaa2018aaaaa
```

Output should be:

```
2018fffffffffffffffff
dddddd2018ddddddddddd
wwww2018wwwwwwwwwwwww
aaaaaaaaaaaa2018
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your attempt so far, so that we can help you with your code. And what does this have to do with winscp?

Comment: I have created a bat file which runs WinSCP script to download a log file (response log) from remote server. The log file obviously downloads as-is (responses from all the requests). Once the log file is downloaded, I want to cut only the response specific to my unique ID.Script within my bat file is as below: `winscp.com/command ^
    "open sftp://xxx.com/ -hostkey=*" "get /var/log/jboss_sit/suFile.log" "exit" ^`

Comment: You'll need to put that and more detail *into your question*. A solution in bash or even POSIX shell would be super easy, but I can't replicate your environment unless I know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not too big, you can do it with GNU grep and the `-z` flag. From `grep.info`:

```
‘-z’
‘--null-data’
     Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated
     by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.
     Like the ‘-Z’ or ‘--null’ option, this option can be used with
     commands like ‘sort -z’ to process arbitrary file names.
```

For example:

```
grep -zo '2018.*2018' infile
```

Output:

```
2018fffffffffffffffff
dddddd2018ddddddddddd
wwww2018wwwwwwwwwwwww
aaaaaaaaaaaa2018
```

Comment: does it not print aaaaaaaaaaaa2018aaaaa ??

Comment: @stack0114106: not with **GNU** grep

Answer (score 1):

Check this Perl solution

```
> cat 2018_match
sssssssssssssssssssss
ddddddddddddddddddddd
2018fffffffffffffffff
dddddd2018ddddddddddd
wwww2018wwwwwwwwwwwww
aaaaaaaaaaaa2018aaaaa
> perl -e ' BEGIN { $x=qx(cat 2018_match);$x=~s/(.+?)(2018.+2018)(.+)/$2/osmg; print "$x\n" ; exit } '
2018fffffffffffffffff
dddddd2018ddddddddddd
wwww2018wwwwwwwwwwwww
aaaaaaaaaaaa2018
>
```

Comment: thanks @stack0114106 and @Thor. Can you please help me with findstr solution. I wrote below code, but it retrieves only the lines matching 2018, but i want all lines between first and last occurrence of 2018. `findstr /s "2018" suFile.log > results.log`